# Arithmetic operation on more than one table in sql

Tags: php

I am working on an SMS project using PHP, so I have got 4 tables, test, test2, exam and total
I am looking for a query or a way to do the arithmetic operation on the first three tables and store it totals, after searching and I didn't find, I came up with this code below:

```
      $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM f_test";
                $result1 = $connect->query($sql1);
                $row1 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)

                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM exam";
                $result2 = $connect->query($sql2);
                $row2 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

                $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM exam";
                $result3 = $connect->query($sql3);
                $row3 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);


                 $var1= $row1['english'];
                 $var2 = $row2['english'];
                  $var3 = $row3['english'];


                 $var4 = ($var1 + $var2 + $var3);

                 echo "<br>" . $var4;
                }
                }
           }
```

And I tried looping with a while loop but it wasn't doing what I wanted it to do. Any suggestions?

```
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM f_test";
                $result1 = $connect->query($sql1);
                while ($row1 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){

                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM exam";
                $result2 = $connect->query($sql2);
                while($row2 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){

                $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM exam";
                $result3 = $connect->query($sql3);
                while($row3 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){


                 $var1= $row1['english'];
                 $var2 = $row2['english'];
                  $var3 = $row3['english'];


                 $var4 = ($var1 + $var2 + $var3);

                 echo "<br>" . $var4;
                }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `arithmetic operation`? What is it that you are trying to do? What is it that you want is not clear..

Comment: percentage calculatiion, avg, and sum,

Comment: Well.. Those are not *arithmetic* operations but *aggregate* operations. Why don't you post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your schema in an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? Then we can help you better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly, you have three relations which contain some similar data, that you need to aggregate/summarize and you need to insert the aggregations into a 4th table, say `total`.

Your approach here seems too expensive to me. You can do what you are trying to do (not in the way that you are doing it already), but how how you are doing now is way too expensive and exhaustive in terms of resources. Since you are **looking for a query or a way** I could suggest the follows.

If it was me, I would have done something like follows.

Assume two tables namely `test1` and `test2`. Their definitions and data would be as follows. Here, I am assuming again that you are using **MySQL**. This could be done in any DBMS, but the **HOW-TO** will vary from one to another.

```
CREATE TABLE test1(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    mark INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE test2(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    mark INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test1(mark) VALUES(10);
INSERT INTO test1(mark) VALUES(20);
INSERT INTO test1(mark) VALUES(30);

INSERT INTO test2(mark) VALUES(20);
INSERT INTO test2(mark) VALUES(30);
INSERT INTO test2(mark) VALUES(40);
```

Now, I need to get the total for the field `mark` on the two tables (note, the fields are matching in terms of their properties). I could run an SQL query as follows. **NOTE** the `UNION ALL` clause, which does not ignore the duplicates.

```
SELECT SUM(mark) FROM (SELECT mark FROM test1 UNION ALL SELECT mark FROM test2) u;
```

This will give you a result like follows.

```
+---------+
|SUM(mark)|
+---------+
|150      |
+---------+
```

This result, you can get into a php script and then run another `INSERT INTO total` SQL statement from php. That is also really not necessary. Because you can enhance your SQL query above, to perform the insertion as well. I leave that up to you. The above example in a working form for MySQL 5.6 could be seen in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cea4476/4)

Comment: Thanks, i can take it up from here and you were right, its was really exhaustive.